# Tons of errors when embedding webpages in HTML

Tags: html, iframe, embedding

I can't seem to embed anything on my website. At first I thought it was just the YouTube embed but then I tested another webpage and it didn't work either. The errors I get seem to change at random. You can see all the different errors if you open the inspect panel.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LAfb.png)

[https://blendertimer.com](https://blendertimer.com/)

Here's the code for the embed. (though I've tried multiple different code variations, none of which worked)

```
<iframe style="aspect-ratio: 16 / 9" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jxU3c0Gjboo" id="latest-video-video"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?
I've done some looking around, but can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your HTML, attempting to be XHTML, is thoroughly invalid and riddled with errors.

Comment: "attempting to be XHTML"? What does that mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For Youtube, you need to log-in to your account then watch a video.

Click on share and select embed.

You will then have the right code for your iframe.

Just paste the code in your html.

For some videos you must click on "watch on Youtube".

Comment: This can't be the problem. As stated, these errors are present no matter what webpage I try to embed. Not just YouTube.

Comment: @BlenderTimer what kind of errors???
Could you be more precise? So, you're able to load the iframe but you get a lot of errors?
Do you get errors without embedding an iframe?

Comment: I don't get errors without the `iframe`. The errors I'm getting are shown in the screenshot in the original post.

Comment: On firefox I get only warnings but no error.

Comment: Huh, same on my side. I only seem to get the errors on Chrome.